# Python: Split CSV file according to first character of the first column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have a series of large CSV files "basename.csv" like:

B1,3,5,6

B2,2,1,5

B3,1,9,0

C1,4,7,9

C2,1,9,3

C3,8,5,2

I would like to split them into different files like:

basename_B.csv

B1,3,5,6

B2,2,1,5

B3,1,9,0

basename_C.csv

C1,4,7,9

C2,1,9,3

C3,8,5,2

I have already done similar things in the past with for loops and ifs, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this with Pandas or whatever.

SOLUTION

Adapting the solution from @chthonicdaemon and @jezrael, I came up with this:

```
def split_csv():
    for dfile in glob.glob('*.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(dfile, header=None)
        for letter, group in df.groupby(df[0].str[0]):
            group.to_csv((os.path.splitext(dfile)[0]) + '_{}.csv'.format(letter), index=False, header=False)

split_csv()
```

Comment: You can do `df.ix[:,df.columns.str.startswith('B')]` to filter the cols

Comment: Yes, thank you, the thing is that I do not know which letters are there present in each file. I can of course create a list of unique letters and loop over it, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution. In addition, your solution also grabs columns other than the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple application of `groupby`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('basename.csv', header=None)

def firstletter(index):
    firstentry = df.ix[index, 0]
    return firstentry[0]

for letter, group in df.groupby(firstletter):
    group.to_csv('basename_{}.csv'.format(letter))
```

Or, incorporating @jezrael's use of grouping by the explicit contents of the columns:

```
for letter, group in df.groupby(df[0].str[0]):
    group.to_csv('basename_{}.csv'.format(letter))
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Whereas both of the proposed solutions work, this is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: There is problem, give a me a sec.

Comment: see `The rough rule is any time you see back-to-back square brackets, ][, you're in asking for trouble.` in http://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html

Comment: And it is in tutorial - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas

Comment: @jezrael I don't think that applies here as the second indexing is actually getting the first element of the string. So the pandas part ends at `df.ix[x, 0]`. I'll reword to make it more readable, though.

Comment: Yes, lambda can be omited

Comment: now it is same as me, rather add previous solution :(

Comment: `df[0]` and `df.iloc[:,0]` is same I think.

Comment: And I think your solution can be accepted, because you get first better idea. I only simplier your idea. ;) +1

Comment: @jezrael I've refined my original idea, which uses a function over the rows - I think this may be faster for very large files, but I've added your idea of grouping over the actual contents as it's simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create `MultiIndex` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of index and use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""B1,3,5,6
B2,2,1,5
B3,1,9,0
C1,4,7,9
C2,1,9,3
C3,8,5,2"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), header=None)
print (df)
    0  1  2  3
0  B1  3  5  6
1  B2  2  1  5
2  B3  1  9  0
3  C1  4  7  9
4  C2  1  9  3
5  C3  8  5  2
```

Another similar solution as another answer:

```
for letter, g in df.groupby([df.iloc[:, 0].str[0]]):
    #print (letter)
    #print (g)
    g.to_csv('basename_{}.csv'.format(letter))
```

Comment: Sorry, I think that the original question was not clear. I have edited it to formulate it as an example.

Comment: I somehow always forget about `.str`. Good catch.

Comment: I often forget for `dropna()` ;) Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code and should meet the requirements of your request.
example.csv would be the csv inputfile.

```
with open ('example.csv') as f:
    r = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(r)):
    row = r[i]
    letter = r[i].split(',')[0][0]
    filename = "basename_"+letter.upper()+".csv"
    with open(filename,'a') as f:
        f.write(row)
```

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that is purely pythonic and does not require Pandas. Thanks!